# Are for loops and while loops always interchangeable

Tags: java

I understand the concept of one having certain advantages over the other depending on the situation but are they interchangeable in every circumstance? My textbooks writes

```
for (init; test; step) {
    statements; 
}
```

is identical to

```
init; 
while (test) { 
    statements; 
    step; 
}
```

How would I rewrite the following program in the for loop? I'm having trouble setting the value for the init and the test if i rework the following program into the for loop form.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class DigitSum extends ConsoleProgram{  
public void run() {
     println("this program sums the digits in an integer");
     int n = readInt("enter a positive number: ");
     int dsum = 0;
     while ( n > 0) {
       dsum += n % 10;
       n /=10;
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: if i want to rewire the following in the for loop for. I would try for (int i = 0; i > 0; i++){ body } but the problem is I don't understand the initialization in my attempt. I know its wrong.

Comment: There are many solutions because you can initialize `dsum` in the first part, test `n` in the second, increment `dsum` in the third, or leave some of them even out of the `for` construct entirely.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the parts "init", "test", "step". I changed that comment. You see it from the many different correct solutions people are posting. `for` invites creative use of these three parts.

Comment: And yes for and while loops are interchangeable in every circumstance. A for loop is just a modified while loop that does all its declaration up front. So it declares initialization, boolean condition, and post loop incrementation. In contrast, a while loop only declares the boolean condition up front. The initialization is usually done outside the loop with a while statement. A for statement can initialize as the first argument, but this is like having an argument just outside a while loop, but with a scope that doesn't extend beyond that. And finally while loops just increment in the body.

Comment: Short answer, with care, yes. You're fretting over a returned homework, not a due homework, right? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int dsum = 0;
for(int n = readInt("enter a positive number: "); n > 0; n /=10) {
   dsum += n % 10;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

As I can't stop myself from writing this, so I'll point it out.

Your for loop: -

```
for (init; test; step) {
    statements; 
}
```

Is not identical to the while loop you posted. The `init` of the for loop will not be visible outside the loop, whereas, in your while loop, it would be. So, it's just about scope of the variable declared in `init` part of `for` loop. It is just inside the loop.

So, here's the exact conversion of your for loop: -

```
{
    init; 
    while (test) { 
        statements; 
        step; 
    }
}
```

As far as the conversion of your specific case is concerned, I think you already got the answer.

---

Well, by the above explanation, the exact conversion of your while loop is a little different from the `@Eric's` version above, and would be like this: -

```
int dsum = 0;
int n = 0;
for(n = readInt("enter a positive number: "); n > 0; n /=10) {
    dsum += n % 10;
}
```

Note that this has a very little modification from the the `@Eric's` answer, in that, it has the declaration of loop variable `n` outside the for loop. This just follows from the explanation I gave.

Comment: Can you explain it a just a bit further. Are the examples not identical in my question?

Comment: @JessicaM... Well, if you declare the initialization variable `init` outside the while like the way you have shown, then that would also be visible outside the while loop, whereas in case of for loop, it won't be. e.g, in `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { }`, the variable `i` is not visible outside the for loop. So, if you convert it to: - `int i = 0; while (i < 10) { i++ }`, then `i` is visible outside the while loop. So, they are not exactly equivalent.

Comment: So, you can create a local scope around your while, to limit the scope of `variable i`, like this: - `{ int i = 0; while (i < 10) { i++ } }`. And now this is identical to your for loop, because, now variable `i`, is not visible outside the block.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. I would don't think I would have noticed that if you had not pointed that out. Thanks!

Comment: @JessicaM... You're welcome :) Generally such kind of things are hard to spot in the beginning. We overlook them, so we don't bother. But, it's worth noticing.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the scope of variables declared in the initializer, there is another time when a `for` will exhibit different behavior, which is in the presence of a `continue`:

```
for (init; test; update) {
    if(sometest) { continue; }
    statements; 
}
```

is ***NOT*** identical to

```
init; 
while (test) { 
    if(sometest) { continue; }
    statements; 
    update; 
}
```

because in the `while` loop the `continue` it will skip `update`, where the `for` loop will not.

To show this via the starkest of examples, consider the following two loops (thanks @Cruncher):

```
// terminates
for(int xa=0; xa<10; xa++) { continue; }

// loops forever
int xa=0;
while(xa<10) { continue; xa++; }
```

Comment: Perhaps the quickest example to show that they're not equivalent is simply: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)continue;` vs. the "equivalent" while loop. One will be infinite(while), and the other not(for). The for loop guarantees the step at each iteration. I'm surprised this doesn't have more upvotes. It's against all the intuition that people have learned about loops. +1

Answer (score 1):

+1, good question

The difference between the two is mostly eye-candy.  In the one instance the one may simply read better than the other.  For your example, the following is the for-loop equivalent in a single line of code.  In this case, however, the while loop reads easier.

```
public void run() {
  println("this program sums the digits in an integer");
  for (n = readInt("enter a positive number: "), dsum=0; n > 0; dsum+=n%10, n/=10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except for the two things:

1. "For" let you declare and initialize your conditions (= variables, btw - more than one variable!)  in it, and then it is cleaned up automatically, as you leave the "For" cycle.
   Whereas with "While" you will have to do it yourself, initialize - outside the "While", clean up - only as you leave the of visibility where your variables (for conditions) were declared.
2. "For" has convenient syntax (and all cleanup afterwards) for iteration over collections and arrays.

Your code I would rewrite this way:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class DigitSum extends ConsoleProgram{  
public void run() {
     println("this program sums the digits in an integer");
     for(int n = readInt("enter a positive number: "), dsum = 0; n > 0; n /=10) {
         dsum += n % 10;
     }
    }
   }
```

Don't forget - **in init you can place declaration/initialization for more than one variable**.

Comment: Yes, essentially, the variable's scope is the for-body.  Of course, this too, can be simulated by a while-loop, by surrounding the while-loop in its own body, i.e {while(cond){}} instead of while(cond){}.  I don't like it much though.

Comment: Isn't it more convenient to put 2 curly brackets instead of 4?

Comment: I wonder if it can be written: `for(int n=readInt("enter a positive number: "), dsum=0; n>0; dsum+=(n/=10)%10);` or does the order change there....

Comment: Wait, in your case n changes before dsum is assigned.

Comment: The step is performed AFTER the body. So, dsum+=(n/=10)%10) will first change the n, and only than modify the dsum. But the original code does opposite.

Comment: See my answer :) The step part is always executed after the body.

Comment: Yes, but in  dsum+=(n/=10)%10) the (n/10) is executed BEFORE you changed the dsum (check the operators priority), So on first pass you delete n/10 and only than ccalculate dsum. In the original example dsum is calculated FIRST, and than the n is modified.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Replace your `while` loop with this. Just leave the initialization part empty.

```
    for(;n>0;n=n/10)
    {
        dsum+=n%10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what kind of difficulties you  have,anyway

```
int n = readInt("enter a positive number: ");
for(n;n>0;n=n/10)
{dsum+=n%10;
}
```